# Open chm file in Windows and Linux from C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, windows, chm

I have an application developed in `C++` running in both `Windows` and `Linux`. The help file is generated as `.chm` file using `HTML Help workshop`. Is there a single way by which I can open the file in both. I found `HTMLHelp WINAPI`. But nothing in Linux.

Comment: Any help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8205/how-to-view-chm-files ?

Comment: Why don't you use and display HTML5 (which is standardized) on both Linux and Windows ? Your "find-a-resource-for-me" question is **off-topic**

Comment: Use a framework like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) to code cross-platform C++ programs (or restrict yourself to the pure C++11 standard)

Comment: Run Wine on Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

You know that the proprietary CHM file format is normally generated by Micosoft HH Workshop (hhw.exe). Please note it’s 20 years old und was first shipped with IE4 and Windows 95. It’s deep integrated to the Windows operating system and Internet Explorer is required on the customers PC's.

HTML Help is in maintenance mode, which means no new features are expected for either the runtime or the compiler. All mainstream development on HH has stopped – but HTMLHelp (.chm help files) is still recommended as software application help (for offline (local) help).

I think you need one way for Windows and another for Linux. Check by code which operating system is used.

You'll find a tutorial connecting on Windows at [User Assistance for your programs](http://www.smountain.com/m_ProgrammingHelp.htm).

- Please look at the first section of Topics entitled "Connecting Help to Your Programs".
- The tutorial is entitled "Connecting HTML Help to C++/MFC Programs".
- It's in .pdf format for easy downloading and study.

For Linux check other CHM Viewers e.g. [Help Explorer Viewer v.3.0](http://help-explorer-viewer.sharewarejunction.com/) for your needs.